# how to solve socket connection error for bulk mails on private domains?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

> {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 72.167.238.32:25"}

```
public bool IsExists_SMTPMethod(string email)[socket connection error screenshot][1]
        {
            string domain = email.Substring(email.IndexOf("@") + 1);
            var servers = _commander.GetMXServers(domain);

            Socket socket = null;

            foreach (MXServer mxserver in servers)
            {
                IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve(mxserver.MailExchanger);
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipHost.AddressList[0], 25);
                socket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                socket.Connect(endPoint);

                if (!CheckResponse(socket, ResponseEnum.ConnectSuccess))
                {
                    socket.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    // If connected, send SMTP commands
                    {
                        SendData(socket, string.Format("HELO {0}\r\n", "machinename"));
                        if (!CheckResponse(socket, ResponseEnum.GenericSuccess))
                        {
                            socket.Close();
                            continue;
                        }

                        SendData(socket, string.Format("MAIL FROM:  <{0}>\r\n", "from@domain.com"));
                        CheckResponse(socket, ResponseEnum.GenericSuccess);

                        SendData(socket, string.Format("RCPT TO:  <{0}>\r\n", email));
                        bool result = CheckResponse(socket, ResponseEnum.GenericSuccess);
                        if (!result)
                        {
                            socket.Close();
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: SMTP server might just reject connection from your ip address for various reasons (to prevent spam mostly), so there might be nothing to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know the SMTP server accept unauthenticated connections on port 25, your code is very limitative but should work for a private SMTP Server. Nevertheless even you host your own SMTP Server, but attempt to deliver an email message on a realiable internet address, the recipient's SMTP server may reject the incoming email because your SMTP server is considered untrusted.

Please review the following configuration of the SMTP Server you attempt to target:

- does the SMTP server accept only client IP Address explictly registered? Even on private domains this is often the case.
- is SMTP on 25 allowed ? or do i need to use SMTP SSL / SMTP TLS ?
- is SMTP server allow anonymous connections? On Internet to avoid spam this is no more the case. Even on private domains authentication may be required.
- if you use your own SMTP Server but attempt to deliver messages to public email addresses, is your server correctly setup to send email messages over Internet? (MX, Reverse DNS, SPF ...)

There may be a lot of reason for an SMTP server to reject the connection. But if this is on a private domain, review your SMTP Server configuration or ask your SMTP Server administrator required parameters.